# LinearLayout does not expand when adding edittext programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

So I am trying to add EditText to `LinearLayout` programmatically. I have added a '+' `ImageButton` on whose click, I will add an `EditText` until there are five. Below is a snippet of my XML file.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">



            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_field"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:background="@drawable/cyan_top_rounded"
                android:src="@drawable/add" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` with id "Container" will have EditText as child. Below is my code for adding EditText.

```
  mAddField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (count < 5) {
                mAddField.setEnabled(true);
                mContainer.addView(getTextField());
                count++;
            } else {
                mAddField.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

private EditText getTextField() {

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    et.setLayoutParams(params);
    et.setText("abcd");

    return et;
}

 private void initUI() {
    mAddField = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_field);
    mContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    et.setLayoutParams(params);
    et.setText("abcd");
    mContainer.addView(et);
}
```

However, when I click on the ImageButton, nothing happens. If the EditText is added at all, the LinearLayout also does not expand. Please help.

Comment: try changing android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Remove weight & set height to wrap_content & check.

Comment: yes this one worked. I set height of both LinearLayouts to wrap_content. Thanks men

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">



            </LinearLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Change ur layout to this it will work fine:(Make the necessary changes according to ur own). Problem is with the height and width of the outer as well as the inner LinearLayout.

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_field"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The view in which you what to add your Edittext dynamically,you have to set it width and height as "wrap_content". So just change your internal layout to :

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
```

I think this will help you out.